# React updating State from Firebase Server

Tags: reactjs, firebase, state

I have a firebase database, that has a collection called "post" and in post there 6 variables (displayName, userName, verified, text, image, avatar). The idea is, there will be multiple posts in the database.

React Code:

```
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    
    //Whenever the firebase database changes, it runs this method
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
            //Loops through all the posts and adds the data into an array
          setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
        );
      }, []);
```

In react, I have two state variables, posts and setPosts. I'm assuming they are initially just set to empty arrays.

Now I have the `useEffect` function, that I am told runs whenever the database changes/updated. First question, how does the function know that the database updated? In other words, how does the `useEffect` function work?

Secondly, I'm pretty sure in the end, the post variable becomes a list of all the post objects in the database. I'm not sure how that happened. I have attached the code that updates this state above, but I'm not too sure how it works. Can you please break it down and explain how it works? I'm also not sure what the setPosts state is used for.

Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above

1. In line 1 - You have used State hooks to set up `posts` as an empty Array. More reading can be done here to understand what state hooks mean - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
2. Next you set up a useEffect hook function (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to make a backend (firebase) api call after rendering.
3. Inside the hook function you are looking up data from the `posts` collection in firebase and bringing back a snapshot of all the documents in that collection. `db.collection("posts").onSnapshot(callBack)`. The callback function is called every time something changes on the underlying database using well known observer pattern (read more in following links https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview,  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot)
4. Then in the onSnapshot callback function you get an array containing documents which is further mapped to an output array using the javascript Map function `snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data())`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp
5. Finally this output array is set in the `posts` variable using the
   setPosts() method.

Hope this breakdown helps and I suggest reading the links in detail so its clear how everything comes together.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm still a little confused on how State hooks works. Is my current understanding correct: post is the actual array of posts. While setPosts is the function I use to update the post variable? So whenever I want to create a new variable, I would do: `const [newVar, setNewVar] = useState([])`?